# Sublime Text 3 Sticky Split

Tags: sublimetext3

Sometimes, when I use Sublime Text 3 for a while with split windows (using the Origami package), the border between splits gets "sticky", i.e. I cannot move it anymore. Which means, one of the panes all of a sudden has a fixed minimum size.

I can resolve that, back to normal, by using command+z, thus maximizing the current pane. But that's not exactly what I want, because it's annoying in cases when I wanted to have f.ex. equal size of two panes, but a minimized third pane. I have to manually resize all panes to what I wanted or had before, which breaks my workflow.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any known solutions around?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out what the deal is.

It has to do with how the window was split, and under certain circumstances, f.ex. a split on the left side cannot be smaller than a split on the right side.

That's the case when the window has been split vertically first, and then the individual panes are being split horizontally. You split one of the panes, and the split can be pulled up and down to resizes the two panes, without any restriction.

Then you split the other pane, and, at first, the sizes look "free to resize", but then you start pulling on the frame to resize a pane, the frame will pop up beyond the height of the other pane's split pane.

The solution is, to resize both panes, if you want to have one of them smaller or bigger. I'd consider this a bug with a workaround.